# How can I specialize a trait with a None-type constraint?

Tags: scala, traits, type-constraints

First, let me apologize if my question is unclear. I haven't quite picked up the Scala parlance yet, so I'm probably conflating terms. I think my example will be more clear, though.

I'm trying to create a trait `Hierarchical` which describes basically vertices in a graph -- any object which can have a list parents and a list of children.

More specifically:

- 1) **A `Hierarchical` may or may not have parents.**
- 2) **If it does, the parents are `Hierarchical`.**
- 3) **A `Hierarchical` will have children, which are also `Hierarchical`.**

Here's my generic trait:

```
/*
  Hierarchical takes two type parameters: Parent and Child. 
  These should be Hierarchicals with parameters Parent and Child as well.
*/
trait Hierarchical[Parent <: Hierarchical[Parent, Child],
                   Child <: Hierarchical[Parent, Child]] {

  // parents must be passed by constructor lest they are treated as None. 
  // (Requirement 1, 2)
  val parents: Option[List[Hierarchical[Parent, Child]]] = None

  // children can be added, so mutability needed (Requirement 3)
  var children: List[Hierarchical[Parent, Child]] = List()

  def addChild(child: Child) = children ++= List(child)
}
```

A specialization to this is a "root" vertex, whose parents will not exist, so the type shouldn't be specified at all -- thusly, it is `None`. Here's my attempt to specialize the `Hierarchical` trait:

```
/*
  A RootHierarchical has no parents. It does, however, have
  children whose parents are RootHierarchicals and whose children
  are Child.
  A parent can be none (Requirement 1)
*/
trait RootHierarchical[Child <: Hierarchical[RootHierarchical, Child]]
  extends Hierarchical[None.type, Child] {
  override val parents = None
}
```

IntelliJ is happy with this, but the test I wrote is not compiling:

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class TestHierarchy extends FlatSpec {

  "A Hierarchical object" should "be constructable" in {

    /*
    Create a dummy
     */
    class DummyHierarchical(override val parents: List[DummyParentHierarchical])
      extends Hierarchical[DummyParentHierarchical, DummyHierarchical]

    class DummyParentHierarchical extends RootHierarchical[DummyHierarchical]

    val dummyParent = new DummyParentHierarchical
    val dummyChild = new DummyHierarchical(List(dummyParent))
    dummyParent.addChild(dummyChild)

    assert(dummyParent.parents.isEmpty)
    assert(dummyParent.children.nonEmpty)
  }
}
```

The error is here:

```
Error:(14, 11) type arguments [None.type,Child] do not conform to trait Hierarchical's type parameter bounds [Parent <: Hierarchical[Parent,Child],Child <: Hierarchical[Parent,Child]]
  extends Hierarchical[None.type, Child] {
```

My question is this: how can I create this specialization? I know that `None.type` isn't a `Hierarchical` type, but how can I specialize for this?

Comment: I think the issue is starting from your definition of the trait.

    `trait Hierarchical[Parent <: Option[Hierarchical[Parent, Child]],
        Child <: Hierarchical[Option[Parent], Child]]`

says something like this item is parameterized with a parent type, which is an option of this trait with the same parent and child types as this instance and by a child type which is parameterized by an option of parent (which itself is an option) and its own type, meaning that child's parent is an option of an option of a Parent.

Comment: I highly recommend having a look at Rob Norris's talk on Pure Functional Database Programming with Fixpoint Types (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xSfLPD6tiQ). The talk uses Doobie as an example but it really applies to any recursive data structure.

Comment: @AngeloGenovese Thanks for the video -- very interesting. Not sure I can use it because he takes advantage of category theory, which relies heavily on types. I am relying on traits; i.e., parents and children can be different types, so long as they both implement `Hierarchical`.

Comment: Your current implementation doesn't reflect that, Parent's Parent must be a Parent, as does Child's Parent (a.k.a current), then the same is true of children, and given that current is both a child and a parent, and that all the type args are invariant and it basically means that all the types need to be the same.

Comment: @AngeloGenovese Indeed. I'll try watching the video again later -- nothing jumped out immediately when I watched it before, but perhaps I'll glean something new from it.

Comment: Check your code, please. This line won't compile: `RootHierarchical[Child <: Hierarchical[RootHierarchical, Child]]`, because `RootHierarchical` is parametrized (with `Child`), then instead of `None.type`, it should be itself (`RootHierarchical[Child]`).

Comment: Then once you write `Child <: Hierarchical[RootHierarchical[Child], Child]`, you say that all "generations" will have this type, because before you restricted both parent and child to have parents and children of same types. As @AngeloGenovese noticed above, with the current types entanglement you force everybody to be of the same type.

Comment: @laughedelic I plainly stated that the code doesn't compile.

Comment: Doing a bit of research suggests this might be a good application of the [zipper monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Zipper_monad).

Comment: Well, you said "IntelliJ is happy with this, but the test I wrote is not compiling" just after this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some brainstorming, I found that the types of the parents don't need to be specified -- they can be some arbitrary Hierarchical type and will have a default `Nil`.

Here's my implementation:

```
// T is the type of children -- they should be Hierarchicals.
trait Hierarchical[T <: Hierarchical[T]] {
  // The parents will be a list of some arbitrary Hierarchical
  val parents: List[Hierarchical[_]] = Nil
  var children: List[Hierarchical[T]] = List()
}

// Nodes that aren't root nodes will have parents specified by ctor
class NonRootNode(override val parents: List[Hierarchical[_]]) 
  extends Hierarchical[NonRootNode] {}

// Roots will have no way to update their parents.
class Root extends Hierarchical[NonRootNode] {
  final override val parents = Nil
}
```

Here's a small driver with some tests: [Ideone it](http://ideone.com/7LDfIH)